# OpenGL ES can't make LUMINANCE FBO work in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, fbo, render-to-texture

I'm using framebuffers to do some post processing shaders on a video renderer. One of the shaders is quite look-up intensive so I would like to change to a luminance only frame buffer to speed things up. I've tried changing the glTexImage2D call from RGBA to LUMINANCE in the initialisation but I then get an error when I attempt to attach the buffer in "onDrawFrame".

The trouble is I have hacked the code together from examples and don't quite understand everything it is doing. For one thing I am also creating a depth attachment, since I am rendering video I don't need any depth information but I don't know whether I can just disable that. Anyway here is my initialisation for the FBO in onSurfaceCreated:

```
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, renTex, 0);

        // generate
        GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fb2, 0);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE4);

        // generate color texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renTex[0]);

        // parameters
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // create it 
        // create an empty intbuffer first?
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texBuffer);
        //**THIS WORKS AS IS, CHANGING FROM RGBA TO LUMINANCE BREAKS IT**

        // create render buffer and bind 16-bit depth buffer
        GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
        GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, texW, texH);
```

And here is the code to attach the buffer in onDrawFrame:

```
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    // specify texture as color attachment
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -.30f, .30f, -.30f, .30f, 3, 7);


    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renTex[0], 0);
    // attach render buffer as depth buffer


    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        System.out.println("Frame buffer not obtained :(");
//This works for RGBA but returns an error for LUMINANCE
```

Anyone got any suggestions? Also can I ditch the depth buffer component or is it mandatory

Comment: Have you tried using GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT instead of luminance?

Comment: @BlueVoodoo I will try this. I'm guessing you mean it is not necessary to bind the colour texture at all, I'll try to figure out how to write to the depth component.

Comment: You may still need the color texture. I was just referring to the glTexImage2D() method.

Comment: Unfortunately using GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT has the same effect as GL_LUMINANCE or GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, the frame buffer doesn't work. Only GL_RGBA and GL_RGB seem to work. The fact that I can switch between RGB and RGBA makes me think my code is probably right, I suspect a hardware limitation (I am using an AML8726-MX with Mali 400 GPU.) Incidently I did speed things up significantly by removing the depth buffer, but I still think my shader ends up reading 4 times as much data as is needed.

Answer (score 1):

GL_LUMINANCE is not a color-renderable format. From [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) section 4.4.5:

> Formats not listed in table 4.5, including compressed internal formats. are not
>   color-, depth-, or stencil-renderable, no matter which components they contain.

The color-renderable formats listed in the table are: RGBA4, RGB5_A1 and RGB565.

Even RGB8 and RGBA8 are not listed in the table but since you can use RGBA8, your device probably supports OES_rgb8_rgba8 and/or ARM_rgba8 extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use two textures as frame buffer targets one with GL_RED_EXT format for Y plane and other with  GL_RG_EXT for UV plane. Second texture will have a half dimensions of first, so you can't assign them in one time to different COLOR_ATTACHMENTS and need to do your rendering twice, with different viewports as well.

```
 #include "gl2ext.h" 

...
    glGenTextures(1, &mYTextureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mYTextureId);
...
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, mCameraFrameWidth, mCameraFrameHeight, 0, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mYTextureId, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, mCameraFrameWidth, mCameraFrameHeight);
...

    glGenTextures(1, &mUVTextureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mUVTextureId);
...
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG_EXT, mCameraFrameWidth/2, mCameraFrameHeight/2, 0, GL_RG_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mUVTextureId, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, mCameraFrameWidth/2, mCameraFrameHeight/2);
...
```

This works on most iPhone and Android phones with arm7+

Comment: Not work for me , it has error GL_EXT_texture_rg extension is not supported